# fluent nhibernate , many to many, no lazy, circular reference

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate

I have two class: **Role** and **User** with a ManyToMany relation
and I maped them like this :

**Role**

```
HasManyToMany<User>(r => r.Users)
            .Table("CFG_User_Role")
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("UserId")
            .Cascade.None();
```

**User**

```
HasManyToMany<Role>(u => u.Roles)
                .Table("CFG_User_Role")
                .ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("RoleId")
                .Cascade.None();
```

But when i get a role from the db i get also the users and the roles of the users and etc...
How can i stop this circular reference?
I tried with **.Not.LazyLoad()** but it doesn't work.

Comment: Adding .Not.LazyLoad means the relationship will be eager loaded. You shouldn't need to specify anything as the relationship will only be loaded when you access it. If you load a Role, it's not until you do role.Users that it will be loaded (assuming the session is still open)

Comment: Do you really need a list of users in the Role object?

Comment: I don't really need the Users actually but when i delete a Role I want the link to the Users to be deleted automatically. And the circular reference come when i serialize the Roles to display them on the page via JSON